# 'Search as you type' with KeyPress Event

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form to execute queries. There is a search bar to search for Items (Vendors) from a local Table you could select and which the Endresults would be based on.

I have the following Items:

- TextBox "txt_Vendor_Search" (the 'Search Bar')
- Button "bt_vendor_search" (Button to execute the Search)
- ListBox "ltVendorSearchResults" (Search Results should be displayed here)
- Table "dfoSelectedVendors" (all Vendors are saved here)

I have a button to show search results.

```vb
Private Sub bt_vendor_search_Click()
    Dim strSearchSQL As String
    
    strSearchSQL = "SELECT Vendor, [Vendor Name] FROM vend_data WHERE " & _
      "Len(vend_data.Vendor) = 6 And ([Vendor Name] LIKE '*" & Me.txt_Vendor_Search & _
      "*' OR Vendor LIKE ""*" & Me.txt_Vendor_Search & "*"")"
    'Update the Row Source of the ListBox
    Me.ltVendorSearchResults.RowSource = strSearchSQL
    Me.ltVendorSearchResults.Requery

End Sub
```

To implement a live search, I select the KeyPress Event of the TextBox:

```vb
Private Sub txt_Vendor_Search_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)  
    bt_vendor_search_Click
End Sub
```

With the debugger I found that the KeyPress event is triggered every time I type something. The AfterUpdate Event of the TextBox also executes the procedure of the button.

It is not super important, as I can press the button or Enter, but it would be a fancy addition to my form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. Use the `On Change` event (`txt_Vendor_Search_Change()`) instead of the `KeyPress` event.
2. Use the `Text` property (`Me.txt_Vendor_Search.Text`) instead of the `Value` property (`Me.txt_Vendor_Search` uses the default property and that is `Value`).

Then it should work.

Comment: Some explanations about how these changes work would be very nice.